# How can I get the URL of a file's folder in SharePoint using Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I want to be able to pull a URL for the "containing folder" of a file I access via SharePoint using Power Automate.  For instance, if I create a folder named `foo` and I have a document in that folder `foo/foo.doc`, I want the URL of the folder `foo`.  Ideally, I'd also be able to ensure this link is shared to my organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested with Matiur's formula and it does not work quite well. Here is a new formula working in my end. You can try both of them.

```
substring(outputs('Get_file_properties')?['body/{Link}'],0,lastIndexOf(outputs('Get_file_properties')?['body/{Link}'],'/'))
```

For knowing if it has been shared. I think is is not doable OOTB in power automate.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the properties of the file by using [Get file properties] action, you use the following expression to get the link to the folder that the file is in.

Property **{Link}** contains the full url of the document and replacing **{FilenameWithExtension}** from {Link} with empty string('') by concatenating '/' at the beginning results in the full path to the folder.

```
replace(outputs('Get_file_properties')?['body/{Link}'], concat('/', outputs('Get_file_properties')?['body/{FilenameWithExtension}']), '')
```

[image]